# Why do I get this error with pdflatex?

Tags: tables, errors, multirow

First, apologies for not having an MWE, I know it makes things harder. I am unable to replicate the problem on a small example.

I suspect there is some kind of bug with multirow and pdflatex.

I keep getting the following error:

```
         ! pdfTeX error (\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format..
         <to be read again> 
                              \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
         l.511 

         !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I remove a table that uses multirow, this error disappears. Note that line 511 is way after the multiraw statements in the tabular environment, it is a random place in the text.

I can't figure out why this is happening, and I googled the error in combination of bug, multirow, etc. and nothing comes up. Any ideas how to either isolate the problem to understand it better, or otherwise understand what is its source?

EDIT: My use of multirow is completely correct. If I use "latex" (instead of "pdflatex") with the .tex file, it compiles fine.

(For the multirow statements, I use the multirow package.)

Comment: it'd be swell to see a MWE

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: ooh an error ive never seen before:-) `\pdfsetmatrix` is a (newish, pdftex 1.40) primitive for doing scaling and other transformations. You have some rotation applied somewhere? graphicx just uses this for rotations as far as I can see

Comment: I would guess that you have a fragile command in the argument to  `\rotatebox` or the `angle` key of `\includegraphics`

Comment: You should be able to make a MWE. Don't start with a small document and try to make the error start with a **copy** of the big document and remove stuff checking each time that the error is there, keep doing that until you can remove no more, then post the result.

Answer (score 7):

Line 511 is the line, where TeX has decided to call the output routine to ship out a page. The output routine in LaTeX starts with:

```
\def\@outputpage{%
\begingroup           % the \endgroup is put in by \aftergroup
  % ...
  \shipout \vbox{%
    \set@typeset@protect
    \aftergroup \endgroup
    \aftergroup \set@typeset@protect
```

Right after the closing group for `\vbox`, the tokens `\endgroup` and `\set@typeset@protect` are inserted that you can see in the error message. Thus the error occurs very likely inside the `\shipout` of the page.

`\pdfsetmatrix` is usually used by `pdftex.def`, the graphics driver for the `graphics`/`graphicx` package for scaling/resizing and rotating.

For analysis the values of the argument of `\pdfsetmatrix` can be useful
(unhappily it is not shown by the error message). But the argument can
be printed on the screen or put into the `.log` file, if you can add the
following at the begin of the document:

```
\let\orgpdfsetmatrix\pdfsetmatrix
\renewcommand*{\pdfsetmatrix}[1]{%
  \typeout{* setmatrix: [#1]}%
  \orgpdfsetmatrix{#1}%
}
```

- Perhaps you can also identify the problematic operation, e.g. `\scalebox`, `\resizebox`, or `\rotatebox` that causes the trouble. Of course, a minimal working example (MWE) would be nice.
- Which version of `pdftex.def` do you use? The file can be located via

  ```
  kpsewhich pdftex.def
  ```

  The version number is part of the first line containing `\ProvidesFile`.
- I do not think, there is any direct relation to package `mutlirow`.

Comment: first for noting that rotatebox is in charge of that, and not multirow (also thanks to David Carlisle). This made me just think that maybe I should use something else for them. I did not have graphicx in usepackage, and I had a hunch that adding that would help (because I think these are where all these scalebox/rotatebox/etc. are re-defined?) -- indeed that helped and it works now.

Comment: @kloop: What is the rotation angle, the first argument of `\rotatebox`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The way pdfsetmatrix is defined, it does not allow xshift, yshift (last two of 6 variables are set to 0) Can it be redefined to enable that (a least in luatex)

Comment: @reportaman xshift and yshift is already covered by TeX. Keep in mind that TeX does not know about the transformations of `\setpdfmatrix`. The current location in the output PDF page must be in sync with the current location in TeX. This is achieved automatically using TeX means for moving in horizontal and vertical directions. If `\setpdfmatrix` is used, the synchronization must be carefully assured (e.g. by using it wrapped in `\pdfsave`, `\pdfrestore` inside a box with `\pdfsave` and `\pdfrestore` at the exact same TeX position, see for example `pdftex.def`).