# After updating MiKTeX, I am getting an error "(\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format" landscape figures

Tags: errors, miktex, landscape, update

I had been compiling my LaTeX files (using TeXnicCenter) without problem until I updated MiKTeX.

Then, several of my files have been unable to compile - all seemingly due to using the landscape function. When I remove the `\begin{landscape} \end{landscape}` code from the tables and figures, then the document compiles.

The log file reads:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.8)  9 AUG 2017 13:32
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.

(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf.sty"
Package: epstopdf 2010/02/09 v2.5 Conversion with epstopdf on the fly (HO)
 ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
 ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 434.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.
))
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 142.
)
("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\lscape.sty"
Package: lscape 2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [english].

No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count87
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count88
\nofMParguments=\count89
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count90
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count91
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count92
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font`cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 11.
 [1
! pdfTeX error (\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format..
 
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
l.17 \end{landscape}

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1457 strings out of 493634
 20430 string characters out of 3149403
 74297 words of memory out of 3000000
 4852 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6376 words of font info for 23 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 42i,8n,23p,319b,226s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Here is the code where it crashes:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\input{../Tables/xxx.tex}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf, color} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{landscape} 
\begin{table}[htbp] 
\caption{Fake table} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ c c c } 
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{landscape} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Off-topic: use `\centering` not `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` within a `table` environment, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/101651

Comment: Make a small but *complete* example so that other can test the issue.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, what more information can I give to form a complete example?  It's not the code that's broken because it runs fine on other machines.  It's something about having updated MikTex on one of my machines that led me to have problems every time I use the landscape command in a table.

Comment: What is so difficult to understand? I want to test if I get the error too. So make a test document.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Ulrike Fischer.  Here's a test document.  Like I said, this runs fine on one of my machines, but on the machine where I recently updated Miktex, it gives me the error listed above. 
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf, color} 
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp] 
\caption{Fake table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

Comment: Works fine for me too. Show the log-file of this example. Don't add it as comment, edit the question instead.

Comment: Log file added. It works fine for me on one of my machines, but not another where I recently updated MikTex. When I add this code \def\pdfsetmatrix{\pdfliteral{2 0 0 2}} following another post here: [link] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161133/includegraphics-error-when-scaling-image), the file is able to compile, but the table does not show up in the PDF.

Comment: "recently updated"? Your log file shows some _very_ old package versions.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the fact that the only package repository available when I try to select manually is ftp.heanet.ie version 31-Dec-69. I thought maybe some repositories were temporarily down, but this has been the case for several days now. This is the case on two of my machines.